# Is there a pattern for comparing potentially nil objects in ruby?

Tags: ruby, null

I need to compare potentially `nil` objects. For instance,

```
Foo.new(Date.new) < Foo.new(nil)
  # => true

Foo.new(nil) < Foo.new(Date.new)
  # => true

class Foo 
  attr_accessor :time
  def initialize(time)
    @time = time
  end

  def <=>(other)
    # I don't know what to do here.
  end
end
```

Is there a pattern to solve problems like this?

Comment: What behaviour would you like?

Comment: Suppose I have users and I want to see which has posted a more recent comment, I would like to compare the comments with `userA.recent_comment > userB.recent_comment`, but userB doesn't have any comments.  I want to create either a `NullComment` class or something that'd respond appropriately when the comment passed in is nil.  userA's comment is more recent than userB's comment because userB doesnt' have one.  But his comment is also less recent.   I have a snippet of comparisons I want in the question.

Comment: You might look at the null object pattern. The general principle is that you create an object that responds to the same messages as a comment, but represents the absence of a comment. Have a look at this: https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwin1_HAndfUAhWlI8AKHQngD8QQtwIIKzAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D29MAL8pJImQ&usg=AFQjCNHRfoCC0mtF0wAuWuWsffHhjt2aMA

Comment: Right, I was looking at doing something like that, but this same issue comes up.  How can I have `<=>` have logically consistent behavior?

Comment: @wry_discontent: what do you mean by logically consistent? The code in your question, for example, is __not__ logically consistent. Either a nil value is less than any present value or it is greater (this defines sorting order, exactly the thing that `<=>` does). It can't be both.

Comment: Forget about nils, even. Take a look at your code. It asserts that `a < b`. And on the very next line it also asserts that `b < a`. It doesn't make sense, does it?

Comment: Is a nil time before or after a time?  It seems reasonable to me that it responds with true to both of those statements.

Comment: @wry_discontent: well, it's not reasonable. If a < b, then b > a, or space-time continuum is destroyed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a `Foo#to_f` method :

- if `@time` is defined, it returns `@time.to_f`
- if `@time` is nil, it returns minus infinity

This way, `Foo.new(nil)` is smaller than any other `Foo`.

```
require 'date'
class Foo
  attr_accessor :time
  include Comparable
  def initialize(time)
    @time = time && time.to_time # time can be nil, a Date or a Time
  end

  def to_f
    @time ? @time.to_f : -Float::INFINITY
  end

  def <=>(other)
    to_f <=> other.to_f
  end

  def to_s
    @time ? @time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') : 'nil'
  end

  alias inspect to_s
end

p Foo.new(Date.new) < Foo.new(nil)
# false

p Foo.new(nil) < Foo.new(Date.new)
# true

p [Foo.new(Date.today), Foo.new(nil), Foo.new(Date.new(2015, 3, 1)), Foo.new(Date.new(2018, 5, 14)), Foo.new(Time.now + 3600)].sort
# [nil, 2015-03-01, 2017-06-24, 2017-06-25, 2018-05-14]
```

## Refactoring with Null object pattern

```
require 'date'

class NilTime
  def to_f
    - Float::INFINITY
  end

  def strftime(*)
    'nil'
  end
end

class Foo
  attr_accessor :time
  include Comparable
  def initialize(time = nil)
    @time = if time.respond_to?(:to_time)
              time.to_time
            else
              NilTime.new
            end
  end

  def to_f
    @time.to_f
  end

  def <=>(other)
    to_f <=> other.to_f
  end

  def to_s
    @time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  end

  alias inspect to_s
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way

nil.to_i is 0

```
    nil_obj.to_i < date_obj.to_i

    Foo.new(nil.to_i) < Foo.new(Date.to_i) # true
```